# Efficient way of checking if a User has permissions from a list and converting results to a dictionary

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i wish to be able to do the following :

1. Pass in a list of permissions , for example: `['can_change_xxx' , 'can_add_xxx',...]`
2. The function would convert it to `{'can_change_xxx':True,'can_add_xxx':False,...}`

as efficiently as possible.

The reason for doing so would be to create a permissions field serializer whereby i would pass the boolean values to the front end to do some conditional rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method on the User model to get the objects permissions. It returns a set of strings. With a little dict comprehension and checking to see if the

```
def get_perm_dict(user, perm_list):
    // Gives me a set of user permissions
    user_perms = User.get_user_permissions(obj=user)
    
    // Iterates through the passed in permission list and see if the user has them
    perms_dict = { permission: True if permission in user_perms else False for permission in perms_list }
```

This removes the need for manually checking that a user has each permission in the list via `user.has_perm`

Comment: Thanks im using this as my answer, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use dict comprehensions like this:

```
def get_perm_dict(user, perm_list):
  return { p: user.has_perm(p) for p in perm_list}
```

Thats a fast way to generate dictionaries, but I'm not sure if django provides a more efficient way to get all user permissions at once intead of checking each individually.

Comment: Hey , thanks for the reply appreciate it , its working . Yep ill need to check if there's such a thing without looping through it